# Namaz E Janaaza of Hazrat Khadeeja (RA)

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad, sahaba, ali

Who offered the Namaz E Janaazah of Hadhrat Khadeejah (RA)??

Some people said that Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) and some people said that Hadhrat Ali Bin Abi Talib (RA).

I want to know the correct answer with authentic reference in detail.

Comment: What effort did you put to get the answer? Do you expect only Sunni Hadith or Shia hadith too? Say, the answer is either of Prophet (pbuh) or Hazrat Ali, then WHAT?

Comment: I expect both Ahaadith.
But I can't get authentic answer from both sides yet.

Comment: Good point brother Azam. I fail to understand the benefit these questions bring to the imaan of any muslim. Seriously what do you intend to get out of this and how does this increase or decrease your imaan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the books of Ibn sa'ad (at-tabqat الطبقات)  ibn abd al-barr (al-Istya'ab fi ma'riftai al-Ashaab الاستيعاب في معرفة الأصحاب ) Ibn Hajar al-A'asqalany (al-Isabah fi tamyizi as-Sahabah الإصابة في تمييز الصحابة) ... she died 3 years before the hijra. At this time the prayer of Janazah was not known so she was buried in Jannatul Mualla cemetery, in Mecca.

Some scholars even say that the janazah prayer was unknown until after the Hijra to Medina!

http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=204751

Answer (score 0):

Has the funeral prayer been offered on Hazrat Khadijeh (PBUH) and Hazrat Abu Talib (AS)? If not read why?
Many rulings gradually became obligatory on Muslims; Therefore, the prayer for the dead became obligatory in Medina, that is, about three years after the death of Hazrat Abu Talib (AS) and Hazrat Khadijeh (AS). The two died in Mecca, and at that time there was no funeral prayer for the Prophet (PBUH) to recite for them.
RK: Minya al-Ragheb fi Iman Abi Talib; Mohammad Reza Tabasi, boostan ketab; p.197